# How to get the last index of model's prediction?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I am new to PyTorch. I have a variable pred which has a list of a tensor.

```
print(pred)
output: [tensor([[176.64380, 193.86154, 273.84702, 306.30405, 0.83492, 2.00000]])]
```

So I wanted to access the last element which is the class. I did that by first converting the list into a tensor.

```
x = torch.stack(pred)
output: tensor([[[176.64380, 193.86154, 273.84702, 306.30405, 0.83492, 2.00000]]])
```

Now, how do I access the last element or is there any better/efficient way of doing this?

EDIT: For further reference here's the code that performs classification task.

```
def classify_face(image):
    device = torch.device("cpu")
    img = process_image(image)
    print('Image processed')
    # img = image.unsqueeze_(0)
    # img = image.float()
    
    pred = model(img)[0]
    
    # Apply NMS
    pred = non_max_suppression(pred, 0.4, 0.5, classes = [0, 1, 2], agnostic = None )
    if classify:
        pred = apply_classifier(pred, modelc, img, im0s)
    #print(pred)
    
    model.eval()
    model.cpu()
    
    print(pred)
        
    # output = non_max_suppression(output, 0.4, 0.5, classes = class_names, agnostic = False)
        
    #_, predicted = torch.max(output[0], 1)
    #print(predicted.data[0], "predicted")

    classification = torch.cat(pred)[:, -1]
    index = int(classification)
    print(names[index])
    return names[index]
```

During prediction pred consists of `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`, `conf`, and `class`.

e.g. `pred = [tensor([[176.64380, 193.86154, 273.84702, 306.30405, 0.83492, 2.00000]])]`

If there are no predictions made by the model then `pred` is simply empty.

e.g. `pred = [tensor([], size=(0, 6))]`

Presently my program stops prediction if it receives an empty tensor and throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WEBCAM_DETECT.py", line 168, in <module>
    label = classify_face(frame)
  File "WEBCAM_DETECT.py", line 150, in classify_face
    index = int(classification)
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

EDIT1:
It seems to work when I check length of the pred but I get this error when there are two or more rows in tensor.

```
[tensor([[212.38568, 117.47020, 339.35773, 266.00513,   0.74144,   2.00000],
        [214.60651, 118.50694, 339.90192, 265.91696,   0.44277,   0.00000]])]
#################
#################
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WEBCAM_DETECT.py", line 172, in <module>
    label = classify_face(frame)
  File "WEBCAM_DETECT.py", line 154, in classify_face
    index = int(classification)
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

How do I make my program sort of just ignore if there are no predictions made at a certain frame and continue onto the next frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the last element with the index notation on the 3rd axis, then broadcasting to a 1D tensor:

```
x[:, :, -1].view(-1)
```

However, I would rather use [`torch.cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html) on `pred`, this avoids creating a new axis:

```
torch.cat(pred)[:, -1]
```

*Edit* - you may check if the tensor is empty beforehand with:

```
if len(pred) == 0:
    return None
```

Comment: Alright thank you. I am going with the second suggestion. But during prediction, some frames are just empty i.e. nothing there to predict which returns an empty tensor. In this case I get an error: ```ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars``` when I convert the tensor with last element into an integer. How can I overcome this problem??

Comment: or is there any other way to get the element without using int() ??

Comment: I see, could you give an example of a starting `pred` tensor with multiple predictions, one of which being empty, please? I'm not sure I see how you can have it work with `cat` in this instance...

Comment: Hi Ivan. I have made an edit to the post, please check it out.

Comment: But wont this exit the function?

Comment: Hi ivan I updated my code but it still throws the same error. I added the if condition right after torch.cat() statement.

Comment: well if `pred` always contains a single element - a tensor (*that can be an empty tensor*) - you should check for `len(pred[0]) == 0`.

Comment: Can you provide a solution that will work in classes where pred has more than 1 elements?

Comment: I'll mark this answer right. Can you also please check out this post that I made specifically for that problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65424549/how-to-get-the-class-with-highest-confidence-from-a-tensor

Comment: I have added an answer, does that work for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226353/discussion-between-harry-r-and-ivan).