# How to get the class with highest confidence from a tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I want to obtain the class with the highest confidence.
Heres the code that performs classification task:

```
names = ['class A', 'class B', 'class C']

def classify_face(image):
    device = torch.device("cpu")
    img = process_image(image)
    print('Image processed')
    # img = image.unsqueeze_(0)
    # img = image.float()
    
    pred = model(img)[0]
    
    # Apply NMS
    pred = non_max_suppression(pred, 0.4, 0.5, classes = [0, 1, 2], agnostic = None )
    if classify:
        pred = apply_classifier(pred, modelc, img, im0s)
    #print(pred)
    
    model.eval()
    model.cpu()
    
    print(pred)
        
    # output = non_max_suppression(output, 0.4, 0.5, classes = class_names, agnostic = False)
        
    #_, predicted = torch.max(output[0], 1)
    #print(predicted.data[0], "predicted")

    classification = torch.cat(pred)[:, -1]
    index = int(classification)
    print(names[index])
    return names[index]
```

The above code works perfectly when the pred has a 1D tensor. But I get an error if the tensor size is more than that.

There are 5 elements: `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`, `confidence`, and `class`.

For example:

```
pred = [torch.tensor([[212.38568, 117.47020, 339.35773, 266.00513, 0.74144, 2.00000],
                      [214.60651, 118.50694, 339.90192, 265.91696, 0.94277, 0.00000]])]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WEBCAM_DETECT.py", line 172, in <module>
    label = classify_face(frame)
  File "WEBCAM_DETECT.py", line 154, in classify_face
    index = int(classification)
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

So I want to access the class with highest confidence. Please let me know how to do that or if there is a better way to do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you will always be looking at the tensor `pred[0]`. So let `pred` be:

```
pred = torch.tensor([[212.38568, 117.47020, 339.35773, 266.00513, 0.74144, 2.00000],
                     [214.60651, 118.50694, 339.90192, 265.91696, 0.94277, 0.00000]])
```

The index of the prediction with highest confidence is:

```
i = torch.argmax(pred[:, 4])
```

Therefore, you just have to get the last value at that index:

```
pred[i, -1]
```

And the class name will be `names[int(pred[i, -1])]`.

Comment: This seems to make sense but note that ```pred``` has list of tensor. So first how to I convert a list of tensor without adding an extra axis.

Comment: Does `pred` always have one element? If so just use `pred[0]`. Else, flatten it into a single tensor of shape `(-1, 6)` with `torch.cat(pred)`.